# margin notes with roman numerals

Tags: sidenotes, snotez

I would like to have margin notes numbered with roman numerals (if possible using the package snotez).

A MME

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage{snotez}

\begin{document}

Il y a dans le texte littéraire (mais aussi dans tout texte) quelque
chose qui est au-delà du langage, c’est-à-dire au-delà du contenu
signifiant et au-delà de la forme individuelle, et par laquelle le
texte s’impose en tant que Littérature.  La littérature apparaît alors
comme un certain langage rituel, un certain ordre sacré de signes [un
certain agencement des signes], éternel, en dehors de
l’histoire\sidenote{Autrement dit, il y a une essence de la
  littérature au-delà du langage.}.  Cependant cette sacralisation est
un phénomène qui s’accomplit dans l’histoire, dont on peut suivre
l’évolution dans son rapport avec l’Histoire\sidenote{Ou plus
  précisément avec l’histoire des idées ?}.  C’est ainsi qu’à chaque
époque l’écrivain se retrouve confiné dans les limites d’un choix
entre plusieurs morales du langage, c’est-à-dire entre les différentes
possibilités par lesquelles il peut signifier\footnote{Bla bla bla.}
la littérature.

\end{document}
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide a compilable starter document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `\renewcommand\thesidenote{\roman{sidenote}}` after loading the `snotez` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xunicode}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{snotez}
\renewcommand\thesidenote{\roman{sidenote}}

\begin{document}

Il y a dans le texte littéraire (mais aussi dans tout texte) quelque
chose qui est au-delà du langage, c’est-à-dire au-delà du contenu
signifiant et au-delà de la forme individuelle, et par laquelle le
texte s’impose en tant que Littérature.  La littérature apparaît alors
comme un certain langage rituel, un certain ordre sacré de signes [un
certain agencement des signes], éternel, en dehors de
l’histoire\sidenote{Autrement dit, il y a une essence de la
  littérature au-delà du langage.}.  Cependant cette sacralisation est
un phénomène qui s’accomplit dans l’histoire, dont on peut suivre
l’évolution dans son rapport avec l’Histoire\sidenote{Ou plus
  précisément avec l’histoire des idées ?}.  C’est ainsi qu’à chaque
époque l’écrivain se retrouve confiné dans les limites d’un choix
entre plusieurs morales du langage, c’est-à-dire entre les différentes
possibilités par lesquelles il peut signifier\footnote{Bla bla bla.}
la littérature.

\end{document}
```

[image]